# When using SSH, the .bashrc alias on that server is not being read, even tough it is set correclty in .bash_profile and .bashrc

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, shell, alias

I use SSH to login to a remote machine. I can save the alias like so, in .bashrc:

```
alias l='ls -lla'
```

but when I logout and SSH in again, the alias does not exist. It is set properly, however, in .bash_profile and in .bashrc. Why is this happening? Every time I SSH, I have to do `. ~/.bashrc` and I do not want to do that. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your user shell with

```
getent passwd ${USER}
```

And look at the end. If it is not /bin/bash, run

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

If you are a domain-defined user, it is possible your default shell is /bin/sh which might be a symlink to bash, but will not interpret your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: This solved it! So the problem was in setting of which shell to use when logging in?

Comment: Yes, when bash is run as `/bin/sh` it does not interpret the ~/.bashrc. This behavior is probably documented somewhere, but in my personal experience I simply changed my user in freeipa to have `/bin/bash` as my default shell and then my rc file was applied.